# Axon Framework - Does it support ActiveMQ integration

Tags: axon

Does Axon 4.0 support active mq integration? 
I understand that it has got amqp-extension, however, it seems to be based on rabbit mq (com.rabbitmq » amqp-client).

Not able to find any examples either.

Comment: did you find any example that supports Axon ActiveMQ integration? Pls share if found.

Answer (score 1):

The Axon-AMQP module supports AMQP 0.9. The 1.0 specification isn’t supported yet. 
The fact that Axon yses the RabbitMQ client doesn’t make it dependent on AMQP. It’s just an implementation that speaks AMQP 0.9. 
It should be fairly easy to integrate Axon with other nessaging systems, taking the AMQP module as an example. 
There might already be community-built modules out there. It’s worth doing a quick search on Google/Github to see if there is anything that suits your needs.

Comment: As I had mentioned, I was not able to find anything around axon - ActiveMQ integration. Would appreciate if you can share any example or sample code.

Comment: A quick Google led me to this repository: https://github.com/sventorben/axon-jms/. It may be outdated, but as it is only 5 classes, it shouldn't be hard to convert it to match the needs of your project.